# How to make function that prints whole week of given date in C?

Tags: c, date

I want to make function in C that prints the whole week of given date. Parameters for this function are day, month and year. I know how to get current date and time, but I dont know how to proceed on this one. I would like to do this using struct tm and search right week that way. Help is appreciated!
What I've been trying so far:

```
void week(int day, int month, int year) {
struct tm *a = tm_mday(month) /* set a to right month?*/ }
```

For example:

```
int day = 15
int month = 11
int year = 2016
```

Output is:

```
Monday 14.11.2016
Tuesday 15.11.2016
Wednesday 16.11.2016
Thursday 17.11.2016
Friday 18.11.2016
Saturday 19.11.2016
Sunday 20.11.2016
```

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Find the day of the week using. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week ; then        do some more coding to print the week.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at asctime(3).

```
#include <time.h>

char *asctime(const struct tm *tm);

struct tm {
    int tm_sec;         /* seconds */
    int tm_min;         /* minutes */
    int tm_hour;        /* hours */
    int tm_mday;        /* day of the month */
    int tm_mon;         /* month */
    int tm_year;        /* year */
    int tm_wday;        /* day of the week */
    int tm_yday;        /* day in the year */
    int tm_isdst;       /* daylight saving time */
};
```

asctime() takes struct tm * as an argument.
It returns a string like "Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993\n".
Then you can manipulate the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <time.h>

const int day = 24 * 60 * 60; // assuming POSIX-time.

void week(int day, int month, int year) {

    // TODO: Validate input arguments

    struct tm arg = {
        .tm_year = 1900 - year,
        .tm_mon = month - 1,
        .tm_mday = day
    };

    time_t arg_time = mktime( &arg );
    if( arg_time == -1 ) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

    time_t start_of_week = arg_time - ( arg.tm_wday * day );

    char buffer[100] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        struct tm* day_of_week = gmtime( start_of_week + ( i * day ) );

        size_t length = strftime( buffer, 99, "%A %d.%m.%Y", day_of_week );
        if( length < 10 ) exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        puts( buffer );
    }
}
```

I believe my solution works for the most part, but there's a fun bug in it, can you find it? :)

Comment: [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) wants `%` in the format specification string. You probably mean `"%A %d.%m.%Y"`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks, I fixed that - but that's not the bug I was referring to :)

Comment: And `gmtime` (which probably should be `localtime`...) wants some Unix epoch time. I'm not sure you are always sure to have a valid one.

Comment: I cant seem to get it work. It doesnt seem to print anything to user. I test it with main function that takes 3 values from command line and then calls this function like this: week(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]));

Comment: I have worked with code some time now. I try to call this function from my main.c like I posted above, but still output is just nothing. I can't figure out what's wrong or why output is like that (I give date from command line like this: /a.out 20 8 2016 but output is empty. :/

Comment: `tm_year = 1900 - year`?!?!

Comment: I switched it to `tm_year = year - 1900` (I guess that was the bug?) but it still wont solve my problem that output is empty when I run the program.